# Galois group of polynomial over finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $f$ be arbitrary polynomial over a finite field.The Galois group over the finite field is ,as is well known,cyclic,and the generator is the problem.
I heard $f$'s Galois group is completely determined, or a generator is determined, when $f$'s irreducible factorization is given.

But I cannot remember the correct statement and its proof, may be the generator is some product of cyclic permutations.
Could you give me the correct statement and proof regarding this?

Reference（webpages, books,etc）is also appreciated.
Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Probably check the finite field section of Dummit and Foote.

Comment: For an arbitrary polynomial $f$ we can define the *splitting field* over a base field, which in your case is a finite field $\mathbb F$.  The splitting field is the minimal extension field in which $f$ factors into first degree factors, i.e. where all the (distinct) roots of $f$ can be found.   Without the introduction of the irreducible factors of $f$, it would be difficult to say much even about the dimension of the splitting field over $\mathbb F$.  That's in part because $f$ might have roots of multiplicity greater than one.